# SQLAlchemy: Test if a relationship exists without actually loading it

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I have a hierarchy type structure in SQLite using SQLAlchemy. 
In my hierarchy I want to indicate to the user that a parent has children, without needing to load all the children.
I know SQLAlchemy uses lazy loading, but the moment I access the relationship attribute, the entire list is loaded. Since a parent can have thousands of children, this is quite a performance overhead for just testing `children != None`.

Currently the relationship is defined as follows:

```
children = relationship('child',
                        cascade='all',
                        backref=backref('parent'),
                        )
```

And I currently test for children using:

```
qry = session.query(parenttable).all()

for parent in qry:
    if parent.children != None:
        childrenindication = [{'Name': '...'}]
    else:
        childrenindication = []

    hierarchylist.append({
                'Name': parent.name,
                'Children': childrenindication
                })
```

It would be great if there was a more performance friendly way to do this.

Comment: But in case there are children, you still need to load them as you are populating the list. So it looks like you will not really save any performance. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well I want to test if the children exist, without loading them at all, if that is possible. In the list I only add an _indication_ of children, ie a non-empty list named children in this example.

Comment: Possibly something like a query that searches for a child of the parent, but breaks at the first instance since then the relationship exists, no matter how many children are in it.

Comment: OK, now i can see from the code that you are actually not loading it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a sample model:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    children = relationship("Child", cascade="all", backref="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(ForeignKey(Parent.id))
```

few options are listed below, where the first one is the most direct answer to your question:

### option-1: use Relationship.any(...) - potentially the fastest

```
has_children = Parent.children.any()
q = session.query(Parent, has_children)
for parent, has_children in q.all():
    print(parent, has_children)
```

### option-2: get number of children using subquery

```
# @note: returns None instead of 0 for parent with no children
from sqlalchemy import func
subq = (
    session.query(Child.parent_id, func.count(Child.id).label("num_children"))
    .group_by(Child.parent_id)
    .subquery()
)
q = (session
     .query(Parent, subq.c.num_children)
     .outerjoin(subq, Parent.id == subq.c.parent_id)
     )
for parent, has_children in q.all():
    print(parent, has_children)
```

### option-3: get number of children without sub-query (good if parent table does

```
# not have many columns
from sqlalchemy import func
q = (session
     .query(Parent, func.count(Child.id).label("num_children"))
     .outerjoin(Child, Parent.children)
     .group_by(Parent)
     )
for parent, has_children in q.all():
    print(parent, has_children)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the great answer, but I wasn't able to get any of them to work. When I use "any" I get 'AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'any''. And with the other options I used the hierarchy I set out in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726372/sqlalchemy-with-multiple-object-hierarchy), and it doesn't seem to work too well with them.

Comment: However, I read up about indexing and added 'index=True' to the ForeignKey. It gave me such a huge performance boost that anything else is almost not needed. Should I add that as an answer?

Comment: Please do add this as an answer. Still, if you do not need to load the data, you should not, even if it is faster than before: it still uses CPU and it will use more memory for all those `Child` object instances.